# Did chakra come from the Juubi?

Tags: naruto

Did chakra really come from the Juubi?

I saw the flashbacks where Rikudo Sennin's mother took chakra from the Juubi and that the Juubi was a tree first. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is close, but not 100% correct. Chakra did not come from the Juubi, but the Juubi came as a incarnation of the tree, also known as [Shinju](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shinju). The fruit which grew on the tree, known as the chakra fruit was first eaten by Kaguya Ōtsutsuki, making her the first chakra user, and the origins of chakra as used now a days.

Bit more details below, but also massive spoilers.

> After Kaguya Otsutsuki (Rikudo Sennin's mother) ate the fruit known as the chakra fruit that grew on the tree, she obtained almost god like powers. Which she then used to single handedly end all wars at the time. This makes her the first wielder of chakra.

> She slowly went insane. On the brink of insanity, she incarnated with Shinju to create the Juubi. After that, she went into a fit of anger after finding out that her 2 sons, Hagoromo and Hamura, inherited her powerful chakra and dojutsu respectively.

Comment: May I ask how do you know that Dimitri mx?

Comment: @NatsuDragneel I follow the manga. I used the narutopedia to cross reference what I remembered from reading.

Comment: Yep, thats pretty much it. Source of chakra was the legendary tree and it's fruit was eaten by Kaguya. Although, the anime sort of also implies that the tree transformed itself into the Juubi to get revenge for it's power/chakra being stolen. Not sure, if what you said about the incarnation, is correct or not.